# Usar NewRelic para monitorar aplicações Java no Tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat

Assim como monitoro o PHP e Django, gostaria de monitorar o `"Browser page load time"` de aplicações [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Instalei o `"Java agent self-installer"` conforme descrito [nos documentos da New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-self-installer). Está tudo certo, estou monitorando diversos recursos da `JVM`, monitoro o acesso ao `DB` e tudo mais.

O problema é que o `"Browser page load time"` não habilita assim como no `PHP` e Python/Django..

Porque?

Comment: Qual o servidor de aplicação que roda Java?

Comment: tomcat7 dentro de um CentOS numa EC2 na AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é exatamente o caso da sua aplicação, mas alguns browsers não enviam as informações que o NewRelic utiliza pra construir este gráfico.

O link abaixo possui trechos de código para enviar a informação:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work#rum-for-browsers-without-the-navigation-timing-api

Devem ser adicionados alguns scripts JavaScript no cabeçalho:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var NREUMQ=[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);
</script>
```

...e no rodapé:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (!NREUMQ.f) NREUMQ.f=function() {
   NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);
   var e=document.createElement("script");
   e.type="text/javascript";e.src="https://d7p9czrvs14ne.cloudfront.net/11/eum/rum.js";
   document.body.appendChild(e);
   if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();
 };
 if(window.onload!==NREUMQ.f){NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};
 NREUMQ.push(["nrf2","beacon-1.newrelic.com","api-key",appID,"cV5eEkBfCF1WRBgECFZEQwNAbwVBQ1peAgdGWF8IQR8LR1ZEQQgDRQ==",6,707, new Date().getTime()]);
</script>
```